# Javascript Query to Set the value in spreadsheet using Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, spreadjs

I need to set a cell value through javascript in Selenium as it has been built through spreadjs and i can't obtain the elements value. 
I used below Query to set the value:

```
        string query = "GcSpread.Sheets.findControl(document.getElementById(\"" + _sheetName + "\")).getSheet(0).setValue(" + rwPos + ", " + colPos + ",'" + strCellVal +"')";
```

Using this query it enters the value but looks like it just enters the value in textbox and doesn't actually set the value.

Any help to how to set the value will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am a member of GrapeCity’s Technical Engagement team for SpreadJS. Our team has taken a look at your question but for us to look further into this issue we will need more information, if possible, a demo that shows this issue occurring. Please reach out to the GrapeCity support team and mention the escalated case number: SJS- 4243.
Best,
Mackenzie

Comment: Thanks!! i got this issue resolved as there was another element over the existing grid, it didn't let me edit it.